# Can't change my lock screen password remotely

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lock-screens, android-device-manager

I've tried changing my lock screen password using the [Android device manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) for my Samsung Galaxy A3 with Lollipop, but when I clicked on "lock" the following message was returned:

> Since Google has verified that a screen lock is already set, the
>   password you entered won't be needed.

I want to be able to remotely change my lock screen password using the Android device manager, is that possible?